# How to make a do while loop restart after certain amount of iterations

Tags: java, loops, iteration, do-while

I have a do while loop

```
int maxItter = 20;
int index = maxItter;
do {
    index --;
    int itterNum = maxItter-index;

    //stuff

} while (index > 0);
index = index + 1;
```

Where `maxItter` equals the maximum number of iterations and `itterNum` being the current iteration the do while loop is on.

After 20 iterations, I want 'itterNum' to restart at 0

How do I do this?

Comment: you can wrap your loop with another loop

Comment: Wouldn't that make it an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I get your question correct. In this case you will get infinite loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maxItter = 20;
    int index = maxItter;
    do {
        index --;
        int itterNum = maxItter-index;

        //stuff

        if (itterNum == 20) {
            index = 20;
        }
        System.out.println(itterNum + " " + index);
    } while (index > 0);
    index = index + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably just want to use a modulo. Can also simplify this with a for loop

```
int maxIter = 20;
for (int index = 0;; index++) {
    int iterNum = index % maxIter;
    //stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be n number of approaches,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int maxItter = 20;
        int index = maxItter;
        // how many times you want to restart the loop
        int numberOfRestart = 10;
        do {
            index --;
            int itterNum = maxItter-index;
            if(index == 0) {
                index = maxItter;
                numberOfRestart --;
            }
            if(numberOfRestart == 0) {
                break;
            }
        } while (index > 0);
        index = index + 1;
    }
}
```